# jquery mobile glyphish icons not displaying icon container background when using local images

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have my icons all setup in my footer using the glyphish icon sets pointing to the demo page glyphish.com/images/demo.png.

However when I download the images and use my own the container images do not display, jsfiddle with code for demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/NkjQr/1322/

```
    <div data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-position="fixed"> 
            <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="d"> 
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#" id="favorite" data-icon="custom" ></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" id="recent" data-icon="custom"></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" id="contacts" data-icon="custom"></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" id="keypad" data-icon="custom"></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" id="voicemail" data-icon="custom"></a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I see the blue icon in the first tab, looks to be working correctly for me.

Comment: Oh I see your comment about black blob background - your image needs to have a background color to see it. Yours is only a transparent png.

Comment: cant believe i didnt notice that lol thanks!